# Passing an enum type as a parameter? c++

Tags: c++, enums

For example i create an enum in one function and save them on an array of animals type, int this case just the cow value, and then i want to pass that array into function2 as a parameter, how do i do it?

```
void function1()
{
    enum animals{cow,cat,dog};

    animals array[3];

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        array[i]=cow;
    }

    function2(array);
} 

void function2()
{
    // blablabla
}
```

Comment: "For example i create an enum in one function"... you might want to read up on *scope* as well as how to delcare & implements functions with parameters.

Comment: For your `animals` type to be usable in both functions, it has to be visible to both functions, which means it can't be defined inside either of them. Also, C++ doesn't have array parameters; either pass a pointer to the first element (`function2(array)` does this implicitly), which means you'll need to pass the length explicitly, or use a container class (`vector`, `array`, etc.; I don't know which one is best).

Comment: @Ben that's a C question; C++ has better options

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can cast the array to an int array and pass it in:

```
function2((int*)array);
```

But then function 2 won't know how to decode your enum.  If you want to use the enum across more than one function, then you need to define it as a global or in some other place that both functions can see.

Comment: Casting to `int*` is still a bad idea. Types `int` and `animals` might not be the same size. And your description still refers to casting to an array type. I suggest deleting the first two lines of this answer; making the `enum` type visible to both functions is the only sensible solution.

Comment: This causes undefined behaviour

Comment: @AnT You could cast to reference to array type

Answer (score 1):

The `enum` definition has to be visible to both functions. For example:

```
enum animals{cow,cat,dog};

template<size_t N>
void function2(animals (&foo)[N])
{
    cout << "Received " << N << " animals.\n";
}

void function1()
{
    animals array[3] = { cow, cow, cow };
    function2(array);
}
```